# Xcode processing symbol files multiple times for same device

Tags: ios, xcode

If I haven't installed our app to my phone in a week or two, `Xcode` processes `symbol files` again. As far as I know, `Xcode` should only need to do this once per device.

What can I do to prevent this from happening?

It wouldn't bother me if it was quick, but it takes about 10-15 minutes. Usually, I just want to quickly test the app, give some feedback to my frontend devs, and move on.

> Xcode version: 8.3.3
>
> iOS version: 10.3.3

FYI, the reason for the delay between builds is most of the time we use Unity Cloud Build which just provides the `IPA`. However, sometimes during faster iteration periods, cloud build is too slow.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another cable or USB port - Other usb port fixed it for me 
or "Rebooting iPhone" or

1. Clean Project
2. Option + Product -> Clean Build Folder
3. Remove this folder Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache
4. Find your project folder in Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ and remove
5. Restart Xcode

Comment: Hi yogesh, this particular round of tests, I happened to be using a different USB port, so that can't be it. Besides, it would be just as much of an issue if certain USB ports caused this sort of thing. That shouldn't be a requirement to simply test our app. As for cleaning the project and clearing out local derived data folders. I have tried this in the past, but I still got the same "processing symbol files" today unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Hold for few minutes, Once the processing symbol files is finished it will not happen again. I tried these steps few times, then I connect my device and do nothing. After sometime everything is ok.

Comment: You misunderstood my issue. What you describe is what should happen, yes. But it is not my experience. Even after letting the processing complete, it happens again for the same device if I connect it again a week or two later.